# grid.arrange render unwanted padding when aspect ratio is defined

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown, gridextra

**Background:**
I try to combine 5 plots in a R markdown pdf output using the `grid.arrange()` function from the `gridExtra`-package. It makes sense for me to lock the aspect ratio to 1:1.

**Problem:**
This works fine when plotting on one row. When expanding to 2 rows, however, the output gets a padding that shrinks the plots sizes which I want to keep as large as possible. I cannot find any setting that avoids this behaviour (changing `plot.margin` does not improve).

I provide a minimalworking example below (save to .Rmd-file to render with `knitr`), but I attach some screen dumps of the output as well:

Fig. 1) If I only use 1 row at the time, the output looks like I want it, but unfortunately not within the same `arrange.grid()` command and therefore with a huge vertical space in between the plots:

[image: If I only use 1 row at the time, the output looks like I want it, but unfortunately not within the same arrange.grid() command and therefore with a huge vertical space in between the plots:]

Fig. 2) Putting plots within the same grid.arrage induces padding (smaller plots)
[image: Putting plots within the same grid.arrage induces padding (smaller plots)]

Fig. 3) Skipping aspect removes padding but, well, also aspect 1:1.
[image: Skipping aspect removes padding but, well, also aspect 1:1.]

**Question:**
Is there any way to avoid this padding behaviour and get maxium size of multiple row arrange.grids within the same arrange.grid-call?

**Minimal working example**

````
---
title: "grid.arrange() padding with aspect-ratio problems"
subtitle: "a miminum working example"
output: pdf_document
fontsize: 10pt
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

### Plots with maximum size, but not within the same grid.arrage-block
```{r plot_problems, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
plot_speed_dist <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) +
    geom_point()
aspect_1_theme <- theme_classic() + theme(aspect.ratio=1, plot.background=element_rect(fill="lightgrey"))
no_aspect_theme <- theme_classic() + theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="lightgrey"))

  grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(
    plot_speed_dist + ggtitle('A', subtitle = "a") + aspect_1_theme,
    plot_speed_dist + ggtitle('B', subtitle = "a") + aspect_1_theme,
    plot_speed_dist + ggtitle('C', subtitle = "a") + aspect_1_theme,
    nrow=1, ncol=3))
  grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(
    plot_speed_dist + ggtitle('D', subtitle = "d") + aspect_1_theme,
    plot_speed_dist + ggtitle('E', subtitle = "e") + aspect_1_theme,
    nrow=1, ncol=3))
  
```

### Putting plots within the same grid.arrage induces padding (smaller plots)  
```{r plot_problems_2, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
  grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(
    plot_speed_dist + ggtitle('A', subtitle = "a") + aspect_1_theme,
    plot_speed_dist + ggtitle('B', subtitle = "b") + aspect_1_theme,
    plot_speed_dist + ggtitle('C', subtitle = "c") + aspect_1_theme,
    plot_speed_dist + ggtitle('D', subtitle = "d") + aspect_1_theme,
    plot_speed_dist + ggtitle('E', subtitle = "e") + aspect_1_theme,
    nrow=2, ncol=3), newpage = T)
```

### Skipping aspect removes padding but, well, also aspect 1:1.
```{r plot_problems_3, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
  grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(
    plot_speed_dist + ggtitle('A', subtitle = "a") + no_aspect_theme,
    plot_speed_dist + ggtitle('B', subtitle = "b") + no_aspect_theme,
    plot_speed_dist + ggtitle('C', subtitle = "c") + no_aspect_theme,
    plot_speed_dist + ggtitle('D', subtitle = "d") + no_aspect_theme,
    plot_speed_dist + ggtitle('E', subtitle = "e") + no_aspect_theme,
    nrow=2, ncol=3), newpage = T)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to set `fig.width` and `fig.height` in the beginning of the code chunk. Playing around a bit, we find that `{r plot_problems_2, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.height=7.25, fig.width=9.8}` produces the following plot. The text and dots are a bit smaller, but maybe it's a compromise you can make.

[image]

Comment: I assumed that there was some "hidden" (or at least to me unknown) setting that limited the image height, but I wasn't sure where to look for it. Great solution. Thank you!